# static vector doesn't save datas?

Tags: c++, vector, static, stdvector, static-variables

I'm a little confused. Indeed, I declared a global vector in a namespace from an header file:

```
namespace foo {
    ...
    static std::vector<T> vec;
    ...
    void append(T item) {
        vec.push_back(item);
    }
    T get(int index) {
        return vec[index];
    }
}
```

When I want to recover one of the vector elements at runtime:

```
foo::append(/* item */);
T ItemFromVec = foo::get(0);
```

I have this dialog box:

[image]

Apparently, the vector would be empty.
I guess the problem is that it's `static`, but I get errors from the linker if it's not static. I also don't have an implementation .cpp file.

What should I do, and why is it doing this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` specifier makes compiler create a separate variable for each translation unit. So most likely you call `append` in one translation unit and then `get` in another translation unit so they operate on different variables.

Given that you can use modern compiler you can mark variable as `inline`:

```
inline std::vector<T> vec;
```

Or, even better, wrap it along with the functions into class and use as private static class field.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then we must make sure that this vector is unique for each function that uses it in order to have the same data. I think using a class will be a good thing, since my functions in that namespace revolve around that vector. Thank you :)
PS: My compiler being modern (not yet C++17 though), inline variables (still) don't work.